# Cypress and Cucumber page objects: static keyword vs instantiating new instance?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, cucumber

In an Angular project using Cypress w/ Cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, we have an e2e suite set up with feature files, step files and page object files. Our original Protractor suite did not utilize the static keyword in its page objects:

**home.po.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

  elements = {
     /// list of elements that the step files can use
  }

  login(user) {
     /// login the user
  }
}
```

**common.steps.ts**

```
import { Given, Then, When } from '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor';
import { HomePage } from '../myPages';

// instantiate new instance of these page objects so we can use the stuff inside them.
const homePage = new HomePage();
const basePage = new BasePage();

    Given('I'm logged in', () => {
      let user
      homePage.login(user)
    )}
}
```

But in our Cypress/Cucumber suite, what are the implications for making all of our page object files utilize the static keyword for everything? Is this a bad move, and what are the reasons why you would or wouldn't exclusively utilize static page object methods/properties in a big test suite? The static strategy:

**home.po.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

  static elements = {
     /// list of elements that the step files can use
  }

  static login(user) {
     /// login the user
  }
}
```

**common.steps.ts**

```
import { Given, Then, When } from '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor';
import { HomePage } from '../myPages';

    Given('I'm logged in', () => {
      let user
      HomePage.login(user)
    )}
}
```

Comment: Static properties can only access static data. Due to the fact that you don't need to create an instance to use a static property, this means you can't access an instance's data via a static property. In other words, this is no different than writing the static method (login in your case) outside the `HomePage` component.